# How to fix a JButton to not take up the whole JFrame

Tags: java

I am a beginner in coding and I am learning Java. I'm busy making a log in system, and I have made a `JFrame`, but when I add a `JButton`, it takes up the whole `JFrame`.

```
public class LogInSystem extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        // Setting the JFrame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Log in System");
        frame.setSize(2000, 2000);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Setting the button
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        Button btn1 = new Button();
        btn1.setText("1");
        btn1.setBounds(50, 150, 100, 30);
        frame.add(btn1);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to change Button to JButton and everything should be Ok.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you declare a panel and not adding button into it as well as not adding the panel to the frame. You can try to add your button into panel and panel into frame,

```
panel.add(btn1);
frame.add(panel);
```

You can also use some useful layout for a particular panel. For example, BoxLayout, GridLayout and etc. By default, everything is set to be FlowLayout.